# Filter out books with low sales

Tags: sql

I have a Books table and an Orders table in my PieCloudDB Database. The Books table records the book id, name and launch date. The Orders table records the order id, book id, quantity and order date.

| book_id | name | launch_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pride and Prejudice | 2010-01-01 |
| 2 | The Kite Runner | 2012-05-12 |
| 3 | The Da Vinci Code | 2023-11-10 |
| 4 | Wuthering Heights | 2022-12-01 |
| 5 | The Moon and Sixpence | 2018-09-21 |
| 6 | Three Days To See | 2023-12-20 |

| order_id | book_id | quantity | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2020-07-26 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2023-08-05 |
| 3 | 3 | 8 | 2023-11-19 |
| 4 | 4 | 6 | 2023-12-05 |
| 5 | 4 | 5 | 2023-12-10 |
| 6 | 5 | 9 | 2019-02-02 |
| 7 | 5 | 8 | 2020-04-13 |

Now I want to filter out books with a total order volume of less than 10 **in the past year**, and **do not consider books with a launch date less than a month ago**. `Assume today is 2023-12-20`.

For the example data, expected results should be:

| book_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pride and Prejudice |
| 2 | The Kite Runner |
| 3 | The Da Vinci Code |
| 5 | The Moon and Sixpence |

I tried this query but I didn't get the correct result:

```
select book_id,name
from books
where launch_date < '2023-11-20'
and
book_id in (
select book_id
from orders
where order_date between '2022-12-20' and '2023-12-20'
group by book_id
having sum(quantity) < 10);
```

My results:

| book_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pride and Prejudice |
| 3 | The Da Vinci Code |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use PieCloudDB; if it supports **outer join**, then query would look like this:

```
   select b.book_id, b.name, sum(o.quantity) total
   from books b left join orders o on o.book_id = b.book_id
     and o.order_date between date '2022-12-20' and date '2023-12-20'
   where b.launch_date < date '2023-11-20'
   group by b.book_id, b.name
   having sum(o.quantity) < 10 
       or sum(o.quantity) is null
   order by b.book_id;

   BOOK_ID NAME                       TOTAL
---------- --------------------- ----------
         1 Pride and Prejudice            1
         2 The Kite Runner
         3 The Da Vinci Code              8
         5 The Moon and Sixpence
```

Basically, it says that

- you should take into account **all** books, regardless of whether they were ordered or not (that's The Kite Runner).
- Join should also contain order dates condition so that it returns books that were ordered but not necessarily in period you're interested in (that's The Moon and Sixpence).
- Finally, the `having` clause must take `null` quantity into account

Answer (score 0):

I applied for a PieCloudDB Database trial account and tested my query. The result should meet your requirements.

```
select book_id,name
from books
where book_id not in (select book_id from
(select book_id ,sum(quantity)
from (select * from orders
where order_date > '2022-12-20') as tb1
group by book_id
having sum(quantity)>=10) as tb2)
and launch_date <'2023-11-20';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.book_id, b.name FROM Books b JOIN Orders o ON b.book_id = o.book_id WHERE b.launch_date <= '2023-11-20' AND,o.order_date >= '2022-12-20' GROUP BY b.book_id, b.name HAVING SUM(o.quantity) >= 10;
```